# mobile project with openshift

Tags: ios, mongodb, mobile, openshift

I would like to develop a mobile app which publish pictures online inside a mongodb on openshift.com.

At the same time I would like to host website where some customers can see a "wall" with all the publications.

My question is: Openshift.com is a good choice when you need to store datas (pictures, text) from smartphones  and in the same time to host a website?

p.s. the pictures will be stored directly in the mongodb, is it a good way to do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would be best off writing a simple API that your mobile application will connect to (in your language of choice) to get the data into mongo.  I personally would either store the images on the filesystem in your app-root/data directory, or store them on Amazon S3.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your quick answer but when do you mean "storing on the filesystem in my app-root/data directory" do you mean localy on the smartphone?

Comment: No, i mean storing it on your openshift gear.